# calling View inside a View in android

Tags: java, android

How to Call View inside a View on click of a button in android.
  Here is my code:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment1 {
    public Fragment2() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // how to call here
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

is there any way to call view on click of button.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: you getting view itself in public void onClick(View v) , what else you want to use as view ?

Comment: i have created tabHost using fragments..In one of the tab i have created buttons so that onClick of that button it should call another view or replace current view

Comment: @jeevan according to your last comment you probably need to learn transactions of fragments . http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing

Comment: Do you want to replace the current fragment in `onclick` event?

Comment: yup got it now..thanks

Comment: @GauravGupta ur right i want to replace the current view with new view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your issue correctly, then, possibly you are looking for this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
              transaction.commit(); 
           }
        });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: can you tell how to replace view using fragments..

Comment: i think replace function works for want i want thanks ill try..

Comment: Go through this, for better understanding, many of your doubts will be clear after reading this, http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing

Answer (score 0):

You can find views of Fragment by referencing inflated views inside `onCreateView()`.

Try:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false);
 TextView txtDemo= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDemo);

 Button btnAnyButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAnyButton);

 btnAnyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           txtDemo.setText("Hello World");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Inside that button function i want call another view or replace the current view with new view..i want to replace old xml layout with new xml layout

Comment: @jeevan Have you mentioned this and have included enough details in your question? Take time and ask question with enough detail. Please!